# Google Payment Integration in web application to make payments using gmail id

Tags: payment-gateway, google-pay

Below is the problem description :-
I have a client in Israel for whom I am helping to develop a web application.
Requirement:
User A, buys a service/ product from the site and wants to make a payment.
On click of pay button, option to make payment using google payment gateway should be available.

I am searching for APIs to make this integration but unable to find any on developers.google.com.
All of the information talks about APIs to enable payments to Google if I am registered with Google as a vendor of google products/ services and I want make them a payment.

To re-iterate, APIs are required to enable user to make payment to the merchant over our website using google payment.

Note : The site will be hosted in Israel.

Answer (score 1):

The information you are after should be available at the [Google Pay Developer Site](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/overview). Some of the requirements for your client are:

- Have a supported [payment service provider](https://developers.google.com/pay/api#participating-processors)
- Complete a test integration (see [examples](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/resources/demos) or the [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/pay-web-checkout/))
- Register as a [Google Pay merchant/business](https://pay.google.com/business/console/)

FYI, Israel is one of the [supported Google Pay countries](https://support.google.com/pay/answer/9023773?hl=en).

Comment: Since the project was not continued, could not verify the provided information and hence have not marked it as the answer. Thanks for your help @Soc